# My Aloe Vera has one leaf that is flattening after I just repotted it, is it wilting?

Tags: plant-health, aloe

[image]

[image]

I've been watering it around twice a week, and it has been getting a good deal of sun, save for some recent rainy days. Yet the largest leaf seems to be flattening out and another feels kinda soft, whilst the others feel firm. It's facing SE, and is planted in succulent soil. I checked the roots and everything seemed alright, but the leaves show no sign of improvement. I was wondering what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Watering twice a week might be too much water.  Even once per week might be overdoing it.  These are succulent/cactus plants as you know, and they store their own water.  This article is pretty good but it says flattened leaves is a sign of too little light.  Has your plant been in this same spot? It should get enough light where you've got it.

Succulents also have very shallow roots.  When you water, don't soak the soil.  Water shallowly.  Looks like the proper pot size.  If you get a chance, I would purchase a shallow clay pot the same diameter but only 3 or 4 inches high.  Succulents especially like the clay pots because clay sorta 'breathes', plastic well, is plastic.  I would also buy a bottle of distilled or 'spring' water instead of watering with tap water. Too many salts in tap water (chlorine and fluoride). Get a matching clay saucer and using tiles or flat rocks prop the pot up to get air beneath the drain hole. 1/4 inch is fine.  Never allow your pot to sit in a water filled saucer. No gravel or rocks below the soil and above the drain hole.

What are you doing for fertilizer?  Fertilizer should be a simple, balanced fertilizer like OSMOCOTE 14-14-14 that you only give once per YEAR.  Seriously, your plant looks very healthy.  [aloe vera care](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index;_ylt=AwrTccwnDw5ZzSkAzbInnIlQ;_ylu=X3oDMTByNWU4cGh1BGNvbG8DZ3ExBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDBHNlYwNzYw--?qid=20100516222155AA8HpX1) Do you have a covered patio/porch?  Putting this guy outside during the summers or when there is no chance of frost or freezing temperatures would help him to grow larger, faster.  Even on a covered porch (NOT in direct sunlight) would give him more sunlight than your window.  This helps to make house plants make more food for themselves, gives them a 'boost' so that indoor plants live longer and look better. I used to always put my house plants on my north facing covered porch for the summer.  When I had a porch.  This place is too cold for them even inside.

Comment: Sadly I don't have a covered porch, and this is the only window facing SE in the entire house. I never thought to use fertilizer, as this is one of my first plants since getting into gardening, I watered it about that much due to noticing that it had been flattening out and drooping, which I assumed was cause by it not having any water. It recently lost a large leaf during repotting, could that be a reason for this behavior? Also it never used to be in this spot and was actually in a north facing window. The reason I don't put it outside is because lately we've gotten nothing but rain.

Comment: That information helps an awful lot.  That leaf is just showing low light levels while it was getting light from your north facing window.  Yeah, you gotta have a covered porch but I think just the change to this window with far far more light than it had will do the trick.  And good that you don't put it outside with too much rain and no cover from the sun.  That plant doesn't like your outside environment.  Leave it where it is, and your plant will come around just fine!  A LITTLE fertilizer is all that is necessary. Those chemicals are critical for photosynthesis.

Comment: Repotting is not a big deal at all.  I think you've got a plant that wasn't happy with the light from a north window!  Too much water and too little light will definitely cause problems like this.  YOU were 'tuned in' and found another place with more sun and now you can deal with overwatering.  Way cool Dylan!!

Answer (score 1):

Too much water. I water mine once a month and as far as bad lighting, put a full spectrum 9watt LED light over it and it will spring back to life in a week. A simple timer will turn the light on and off at set times of your choice.